# Put this PHP action in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

i have this action where i get the data via post in array format and save it to a database , this part works but im trying to do this via ajax, i think im having problems getting the data from the form or maybe sending the data to my php script.

```
<?php
  $elegido = $_POST['producto'];
  if(empty($elegido))  {
    echo("No has seleccionado suficientes productos");
  } 
  else  {
    $N = count($elegido);
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)  {
    $elegidos =  $elegido[$i];
    $conn=mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
    mysql_select_db("database",$conn);
    $query = "INSERT INTO table (column)";
    $query .= "VALUES ('".$elegidos."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die("Error sending data.<br>");   
  }
 echo("Los datos fueron enviados correctamente, ¡gracias por participar!");
}
?>
```

i implemented this but it doesnt work

```
jQuery(function($) { 
$("#enviar").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var opciones = {
            method:"post",
            url:"procesar.php",
            producto = [];
            data:{
                data: {producto:producto},
            },
            success:function(result){
                $("body .mensaje").remove();
                if(result=="exito"){
                    $("body").append("<div class='mensaje'>Datos Enviados!</div>");
                }else{
                    $("body").append("<div class='error'>ERROR</div>");
                }   
            }   
        };
    $.ajax(opciones);   
 });
 });
```

any clue on whats going on?

Comment: Have you used a web inspector like Firebug or one native to your browser and confirmed that an HTTP.POST request is being sent? It'll be under the "Network" or "Connections" tab.

Comment: Do a var_dump($_POST) on top to see what is the $_POST variable getting

Comment: I think you have a javascript error. I'm not sure what the producto = []; is doing in your opciones object..

Comment: `"i think im having problems"` - What makes you think that?  Is there a specific indication that something isn't working as expected?  Is there an error?  When you debug this, where does it fail?  Please provide details.

Comment: @WhiskeyTangoFoxtrot yes a request is being sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error (the whole line of `producto = [];`) and you are not sending the variables from the form to the php script.

This:

```
        url:"procesar.php",
        producto = [];
        data:{
            data: {producto:producto},
        },
```

Should be something like:

```
        url:"procesar.php",
        data: $('form').serialize(),
```

Comment: im getting my array from a set of 15 checkboxes from wich the user selects 5, im storing their values , will this still work?

Comment: @user2770956 If it used to work with a conventional (non-ajax) form submit, it should work the same way like this. You do have jQuery included, right?

Comment: but, do i have to change the way i get the data in my php script?

Comment: @user2770956 No, jQuery will make a normal post request just like when you submit the form normally.

Comment: thank you @jeroen i did this and im getting my array stored in the db, however, my error mesagge keeps displaying instead the success msg..

Comment: i got it, i wasnt echoing "exito" at the end of my php script, now its working correctly, many thanks, saludos desde Chile!

Answer (score 1):

`data` should be like this:

```
// data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }

jQuery(function($) { 
$("#enviar").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var opciones = {
            method:"post",
            url:"procesar.php",
            producto = [],
            data:{ producto: producto }, // 'producto' will be an empty array, as you defined above.
            },
            success:function(result){
                $("body .mensaje").remove();
                if(result=="exito"){
                    $("body").append("<div class='mensaje'>Datos Enviados!</div>");
                }else{
                    $("body").append("<div class='error'>ERROR</div>");
                }   
            }   
        };
    $.ajax(opciones);   
 });
 });
```

Comment: thank you, with that correction im getting my own error and the table is not populating.. the problem is in the jquery function when i get the array and pass it as json

Comment: as jeroen spotted you have a syntax error in the line where you declare producto = []